# WordPress add_setting_section does not recognise custom page

Tags: wordpress

I trying to create a custom settings page for my plugin, but I'm unable to make the page display a custom settings page, to make things simple I just want to display the section header.

Here is what I have.

```
private function add_hooks() {
  add_action('admin_menu', array($this,'register_menu'));
  add_action("admin_init", array($this,"display_options"));
}

public function register_menu() {
        add_menu_page('Feed','API FEED','manage_options','adt-feed',array($this,'include_admin_page'),'dashicons-format-image');
    }


public function include_admin_page() {
    return include_once( PLUGIN_PATH 'admin/view/config-page.php' );
}

 public function display_options()
    {
        //section name, display name, callback to print description of section, page to which section is attached.
        add_settings_section("adt_general_section", "Header Options", array($this, "display_header_options_content"), "adt-feed");
}

public function display_header_options_content() { //THIS NEVER GETS CALLED
        echo "PLUGIN HEADER SECTION";
    }
```

and them in my config-page.php i have:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"></div>
    <h1>ADT Feed Options</h1>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php

        //add_settings_section callback is displayed here. For every new section we need to call settings_fields.
        settings_fields("adt_general_section");


        // Add the submit button to serialize the options
        submit_button();

        ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Using some "die()" calls i manage to find that display_header_options_content never gets called, if i change "adt-feed" for "general" in the add_settings_section, i can see the message: "PLUGIN HEADER SECTION" in the General settings page.

thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call

```
do_settings_sections( 'adt-feed' );
```

in config-page.php.

A good place to put this is just before the call to submit_button();